# Bootstrap does not load in login and register routes

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, npm, laravel-8, laravel-ui

I wanted to install a new project of Laravel 8, so I coded this:

`laravel new projectname`

Then:

`composer require laravel/ui`

And after that:

`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

And finally:

`npm install && npm run dev`

but when I load the page login, it shows me this:

[image: capture]

So why Bootstrap does not load, however I tried installing it by the command `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`.

And this is also my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0"
    }
```

So what should I do now in order to load Bootstrap for my authentication routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have not installed the Bootstrap itself into your project, so first install it using below Artisan command:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

and then run the NPM commands:

```
npm install
```

and

```
npm run dev
```

and then refresh your page to see the result.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` will also install Bootstrap!

Comment: No, that actually merely creates the scaffoldings for the Authentication based on boostrap style, not the bootstrap itself.

Comment: So for creating auth routes, should I use `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` or `php artisan ui vue --auth` ?

Comment: If you are using react as your front-end solution then the second one, but else the first one is fine.